# Emoji via CURL in \ PowerShell \ 7 \ are sent to the telegram chat as questions(???)

Tags: powershell, curl

I use:

shell: `C: \ Program Files \ PowerShell \ 7 \ pwsh.EXE`

I send in CURL telegrams with emoji, but they are sent as question marks. How to encode emoji so that they are sent as emoticons?

```
send_msg () {
    curl -s -X POST $ {URL} -d chat_id = $ TELEGRAM \
        -d text = "$ 1" -d parse_mode = $ {PARSE_MODE}
}

send_msg "   ️ "
```

[image]

Comment: `$ {PARSE_MODE}`, `$ TELEGRAM`... are not valid ways to reference a variable

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate answers your question. Separately, please remove the extraneous space characters from the code in your question.